# Chained dropdown list in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to chain some drop down lists in an ASP.NET gridview control that is bound to a LinqDataSource. When I click on the 'Edit' command field the dropdowns display as they are supposed to. When the user changes the first dropdown I'd like the second to repopulate based on the selection of the first. Here is my gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAreas" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="grid pad5 full" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="ldsAreas">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division" SortExpression="CDB_BusinessUnit.CDB_Division.Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("CDB_BusinessUnit.CDB_Division.Name") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboDivision" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="ldsDivisions" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%#Eval("CDB_BusinessUnit.DivisionID") %>' AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboDivision_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsDivisions" runat="server" ContextTypeName="CommonDB_Management.CommonDBDataContext" EntityTypeName="" Select="new (ID, Name)" TableName="CDB_Divisions" OrderBy="Name" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Business Unit" SortExpression="CDB_BusinessUnit.Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("CDB_BusinessUnit.Name") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboBusinessUnit" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="ldsBusinessUnits" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("BusinessUnitID") %>' />
                <asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsBusinessUnits" runat="server" ContextTypeName="CommonDB_Management.CommonDBDataContext" EntityTypeName="" TableName="CDB_BusinessUnits" Where="DivisionID == @DivisionID" >
                    <WhereParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cboDivision" Name="DivisionID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                    </WhereParameters>
                </asp:LinqDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="center" HeaderText="Edit" ValidationGroup="gv" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="center" HeaderText="Delete" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsAreas" runat="server" ContextTypeName="CommonDB_Management.CommonDBDataContext" EnableDelete="True" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True" EntityTypeName="" TableName="CDB_Areas" OrderBy="CDB_BusinessUnit.CDB_Division.Name, CDB_BusinessUnit.Name, Name"></asp:LinqDataSource>
```

As you can see in the second column (Division), I am using the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event to try and re-bind the second dropdown list. Here's the code in the event:

```
protected void cboDivision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList cboBusinessUnit = gvAreas.Rows[gvAreas.EditIndex].FindControl("cboBusinessUnit") as DropDownList;
    cboBusinessUnit.DataBind();
}
```

My problem is that the above code blows up on the `DataBind()` call with the message:

`Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.`

The control `cboBusinessUnit` is clearly bound to the LinqDataSource that exists right below it. Why am I getting this message, and any suggestions on the proper way to do this?

Comment: Why do you have to bind the SelectedValue field for your cboBusinessUnit dropdownlist?  What if you take that out?

Comment: The user needs to be able to save BusinessUnitID for the record. If I remove SelectedValue then they won't be able to update the business unit (and it won't show the correct business unit for the record).

Comment: It does get rid of the error though when I remove that... So maybe I'll have to set BusinessUnitID manually in the code-behind...

Comment: Hmm..Need to think about this some more....

Comment: Can you try this.  Add back the SelectedValue property but this time use <%#  Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BusinessUnitId") %>

Comment: Same issue. I think I have it figured out though now that I know it was the SelectedValue property that was blowing up :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I couldn't get it working properly using the DropDownList's `SelectedValue` property and the LinqDataSource ControlParameter, so I had to do pretty much everything in the code-behind. Here is what I ended up with:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAreas" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="grid pad5 full" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="ldsAreas" OnRowUpdating="gvAreas_RowUpdating" OnRowDataBound="gvAreas_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" Visible="false" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division" SortExpression="CDB_BusinessUnit.CDB_Division.Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("CDB_BusinessUnit.CDB_Division.Name") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboDivision" runat="server" DataSourceID="ldsDivisions" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cboDivision_SelectedIndexChanged" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:LinqDataSource ID="ldsDivisions" runat="server" ContextTypeName="CommonDB_Management.CommonDBDataContext" EntityTypeName="" Select="new (ID, Name)" TableName="CDB_Divisions" OrderBy="Name" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Business Unit" SortExpression="CDB_BusinessUnit.Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Eval("CDB_BusinessUnit.Name") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="cboBusinessUnit" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="center" HeaderText="Edit" ValidationGroup="gv" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" HeaderStyle-CssClass="center" ItemStyle-CssClass="center" HeaderText="Delete" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void cboDivision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList cboDivision = gvAreas.Rows[gvAreas.EditIndex].FindControl("cboDivision") as DropDownList;
    DropDownList cboBusinessUnit = gvAreas.Rows[gvAreas.EditIndex].FindControl("cboBusinessUnit") as DropDownList;

    cboBusinessUnit.Items.Clear();

    if (cboDivision.SelectedValue != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboDivision.SelectedValue))
    {
        var businessUnits = db.CDB_BusinessUnits.Where(b => b.DivisionID == Convert.ToInt32(cboDivision.SelectedValue)).OrderBy(b => b.Name);
        cboBusinessUnit.DataSource = businessUnits;
    }
    else
    {
        var businessUnits = db.CDB_BusinessUnits.Where(b => b.DivisionID == null).OrderBy(b => b.Name);
        cboBusinessUnit.DataSource = businessUnits;
    }

    cboBusinessUnit.DataBind();
}

protected void gvAreas_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList cboBusinessUnit = gvAreas.Rows[gvAreas.EditIndex].FindControl("cboBusinessUnit") as DropDownList;

    if (cboBusinessUnit.SelectedValue != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(cboBusinessUnit.SelectedValue))
    {
        e.NewValues["BusinessUnitID"] = Convert.ToInt32(cboBusinessUnit.SelectedValue);
    }
    else
    {
        e.NewValues["BusinessUnitID"] = null;
    }
}

protected void gvAreas_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
    {
        CDB_Area area = e.Row.DataItem as CDB_Area;

        if (area.BusinessUnitID != null)
        {
            DropDownList cboDivision = e.Row.FindControl("cboDivision") as DropDownList;
            DropDownList cboBusinessUnit = e.Row.FindControl("cboBusinessUnit") as DropDownList;

            if (area.CDB_BusinessUnit.DivisionID != null)
            {
                cboDivision.Items.FindByValue(area.CDB_BusinessUnit.DivisionID.ToString()).Selected = true;

                var businessUnits = db.CDB_BusinessUnits.Where(b => b.DivisionID == area.CDB_BusinessUnit.DivisionID).OrderBy(b => b.Name);
                cboBusinessUnit.DataSource = businessUnits;
            }
            else
            {
                var businessUnits = db.CDB_BusinessUnits.Where(b => b.DivisionID == null).OrderBy(b => b.Name);
                cboBusinessUnit.DataSource = businessUnits;
            }

            cboBusinessUnit.DataBind();
            cboBusinessUnit.Items.FindByValue(area.BusinessUnitID.ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling cboBusinessUnit.DataBind(); on your dropdownlist before assigning any data to it the DataSource needs to be set before calling DataBind()

```
cboBusinessUnit.DataSource = ?
```

But also from the error I'd say your GridView might be becoming unbound on postback. Perhaps if we had your Page_Load method and DataBinding method we could tell you more.

Update.
Yeah did read about data source, just didn't take it in!! So would still look at when things bind etc

Comment: The datasource of the dropdownlist isn't set in the code-behind, it's bound to the LinqDataSource that exists in the GridView itself. The only code that's in the code-behind is displayed in the question (`cboDivision_SelectedIndexChanged`). But you may right, this might be an order issue, the event is fired before the datasource is bound.

Comment: Figured it out, but awarded you the bounty so it didn't go to waste and your answer was the closest. Thanks for taking a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void cboDivision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
cboBusinessUnit.DataSource= gvAreas.Rows[gvAreas.EditIndex].FindControl("cboBusinessUnit") as DropDownList;

cboBusinessUnit.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: The datasource is provided as an attribute of the control, why do I have to provide it again? `DataSourceID="ldsBusinessUnits" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID"`

Comment: We cant directly bind the dropdownlist without providing data source. What i understand in your case is you are trying to rebind the second list(change the list items) based on the selection of the first list, so in order to do that you have to rebind the second list provided with data source and then rebind the list.

Comment: The datasource is provided: `DataSourceID="ldsBusinessUnits"`